# Gulp Sass error when using map.get() instead of map-get()

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass, sass-maps

In Visual Studio I'm using Gulp to compile Sass, using gulp-sass 4.0.2. When I use `map.get()` to get a mapped value, I get an error in Task Runner Explorer, but when I use `map-get()`, it works fine. So apparently it recognizes the latter syntax, but not the former.

**Is there any documentation on these 2 different syntaxes, details on which is compatible with what, etc.?**

In [this documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/map) there is one mention of the `map-get()` syntax at the top, with no explanation or details. And in [this documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps) there's no mention of the `map-get()` syntax at all.